# ASP.NET sample applications

Tags: asp.net, starter-kits

anyone know of some well written (but not too complex) ASP.NET web applications/websites that i could download from code.google.com or something? i just want to peek at how some other projects look to get some ideas for how to structure my project before it goes live. many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check here : [Microsoft Official ASP.NET Starter Kits](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/).  Lots of good stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

[CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search) has a lot of the microsoft asp.net open source projects, also a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **ASP.NET MVC 2** for new web development.

You can find proper 'real-world' sample application called NerdDinner and 185-page PDF walkthrough 'how-each-line-was-written on [Code Plex](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/). Nerd Dinner has many nice features, like intergration with maps or OpenID.

Running app is here: http://www.nerddinner.com/